# Google Firebase is not allowing me to append data with db.collection.doc.push.set

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have node project and I am trying to integrate google firebase as the database for the project. I currently have it so that I can get the data from the database when it is called. I set the initial record and now I am trying to append records to the google firebase database.

It is giving me and error that says there is no function called `.push()` when I call `db.collection(...).doc(...).push().set(...)`. I am not sure why because the documentation says that it should be appending new records to the databse. Not sure what to do.

Here is my current code:

```
  post: (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    newReivew = {
      rating: "",
      user: {
        id: "feaer323vwe",
        profile_url: "",
        image_url: "",
        name: "John Doe Jr",
      },
      text: "Thsi is a third review",
      time_created: "asdffeasvsesv",
      url: "hoots:google.com",
    };
    db.collection("reviews").doc("yelp_reviews").push().set(newReivew);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `push` method is part of the Firebase Realtime Database API, and does not exist on Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API for the one can't necessarily be applied to the other.

To [add a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) to Firestore, use `add()`:

```
db.collection("reviews").doc("yelp_reviews").add(newReivew);
```